# Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented, : Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)

Tags: r

I'm doing an analysis using the Bayesian car, then when I'm analyzing I get an error confirmation

```
Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  : 
  Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)
```

while doing `W.nb <- poly2nb(prov, row.names = rownames(prov@data))` . . . where is my mistake, even though the dataframe is the same

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough the question is older, for completness.

Without reproducible data its hard to state the problem. Two "solutions" seem to be possible, according to https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1762:

1. run first:  `sf_use_s2(FALSE)`

OR

2. `poly2nb(st_make_valid(prov))`

Without the exact data it's impossible to tell, which is the better way.